# convert base-64 spki string into public key

Tags: python, cryptography, elliptic-curve, python-cryptography

I'm trying to find a python equivalent of this js function:

```js
/**
* Generating the shared secret with the merchant private key and the ephemeral public key(part of the payment token data)
* using Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (id-ecDH 1.3.132.1.12).
* As the Apple Pay certificate is issued using prime256v1 encryption, create elliptic curve key instances using the package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ec-key
*/
sharedSecret (privatePem) {
    const prv = new ECKey(privatePem, 'pem') // Create a new ECkey instance from PEM formatted string
    const publicEc = new ECKey(this.ephemeralPublicKey, 'spki') // Create a new ECKey instance from a base-64 spki string
    return prv.computeSecret(publicEc).toString('hex') // Compute secret using private key for provided ephemeral public key
  }
```

public key i try to convert:
(should be a base-64 spki string?)

```
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEYtpZKqPDqavs4KzNnMoxWdIThKe/ErKMI/l34Y9/xVkt4DU4BrCaQnGLlRGx+Pn/WHPkQg3BYoRH4xUWswNhEA==
```

What i manage to do:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec import SECP256R1, EllipticCurvePublicKey, ECDH
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key

def __compute_shared_secret(ephemeral_public_key: str) -> bytes:
    curve = SECP256R1()
    key = base64.b64decode(ephemeral_public_key)
    public_key = EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point(curve, key)  # problem here
    server_private_key = load_pem_private_key(<private_key>, password=None)
    shared_secret = server_private_key.exchange(ECDH(), public_key)
    return shared_secret
```

```sh
ValueError: Unsupported elliptic curve point type
```

From what i understand i need to convert the public key to something before using it in EllipticCurvePublicKey, but i can't figure what type of conversion i should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ec-key#instantiating-from-encoded-keys) of the JavaScript library the line

```js
const publicEc = new ECKey(this.ephemeralPublicKey, 'spki')
```

imports a Base64 encoded X.509/SPKI DER key.

---

In Python, this can be done with [`load_der_public_key()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.load_der_public_key) of the Cryptography library as follows:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_der_public_key
import base64
...
public_key = load_der_public_key(base64.b64decode(ephemeral_public_key))
```

Here, `ephemeral_public_key` is the Base64 encoded X.509/SPKI DER key.

With this change of the Python code the shared secret can be determined.